# GRUB2 not working after installing xubuntu 14.04

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, xubuntu, uefi

I have a vaio laptop and it used to have installed windows 8 and Xubuntu 13.04 in dual boot, everything was working fine.

I decided to update my version of xubuntu 14.04 LTS mainly because the support for 13.04 is finished and LTS version have 3 years of support. What I did was to format the partition where xubuntu 13.04 was installed and install 14.04 in that formated partition. When I restarted my computer willing to start using my new system I got the following message:

> error: symbol 'grub_term_highlight_color' not found

and I was not able to enter any OS.

I tried boot-repair from live USB  more than two times and it did not fix the problem.

I tried to enter to my computer using super GRUB2 disk, however it does not apperar to work with UEFI active (besides super grub2 disk says it can) I only get the message "no operating system found".

If I boot super grub2  disk with UEFI disabled, super grub2 disk can not detect any OS,I also tried Rescatux distro, however, as of super grub2 disk, rescatux cannot enter when UEFI is active.

I tried boot-repair with the option of "restore EFI backups", after that I was able to boot on windows, but no grub menu appeared. I ran boot-repair again with no improving results

Here is the last Bootinfo report I got:

> http://paste.ubuntu.com/7609801/

Do you have any idea of what is happening?

I really appreciate your help,

Best regards,

**Update**

Hi and thanks for your suggestions.

I was able to enter my different OSes using rEFInd (secure boot disabled), however, after different tries I was not able to get a boot menu (either GRUB or rEFInd) to select an OS :(

I tried to install rEFInd in my hard disk, however, when booting it goes directly to windows.

I tried again boot repair, nothing happen.

I tried dpkg-reconfigure, nothing happen.

Here is the last bootinfo summary I got.

> http://paste.ubuntu.com/7651147/

The only way for now to enter Xubuntu in my computer is using rEFInd USB with secure boot disabled.

Thanks for your help,

Any comment is appreciated

Answer (score 1):

See this bug report:
Ubuntu 14.04 Update breaks grub, resulting in "error: symbol 'grub_term_highlight_color' not found"

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/grub2/+bug/1289977

You need to chroot &   use dpkg-reconfigure grub-pc instead of grub-install directly, so that the system knows that it needs to run grub-install on that drive the next time grub is upgraded.

Boot-Repair has a chroot total uninstall and reinstall of grub, which may work or while in chroot run the dpkg update.

Comment: *Do not* install `grub-pc` on the system in question; that computer uses EFI, and `grub-pc` is the BIOS-mode version of GRUB. It's conceivable that something similar with `grub-efi-amd64` would work, but I've not tested that. See my own answer for an alternative.

Answer (score 1):

I can't say much about a fix involving GRUB. (I've never much cared for GRUB 2, and I try to avoid it as much as possible.) I do have an alternative, though:

1. Enter the firmware and disable Secure Boot. (You can re-enable it later if you like, but it's easiest to turn it off for now.)
2. Prepare a USB flash drive or CD-R with the appropriate image of my [rEFInd boot manager.](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/getting.html)
3. Boot to rEFInd. You should see at least one option for Windows and at least one option for Ubuntu.
4. Test the rEFInd boot options. It's OK if some don't work, so long as you can get into both Windows and Ubuntu. If not, stop and report back or try another approach.
5. If you can boot both Ubuntu and Windows, boot to Ubuntu and install rEFInd there. You can use the Debian-package download link near the top of the downloads page or use the PPA described later on that page.

When you reboot, you'll be brought into rEFInd and should be able to boot both OSes, bypassing GRUB. If you've got stray entries, you can remove them by deleting files or by editing the `/boot/efi/EFI/refind/refind.conf` file: Uncomment the `dont_scan_dirs` or `dont_scan_files` line and adjust the values to blacklist the unwanted entries. If you disabled Secure Boot but want it active, you may be able to enable it at this point, although you may have to register the `refind.cer` or `refind_local.cer` key (a program to do so should launch when you reactivate Secure Boot and reboot; the file should be in the `EFI\refind\keys` directory on the ESP). That said, Secure Boot can be a bit hairy, and you may need to jump through some more hoops to use it.

Comment: I was able to enter my different OSes using rEFInd (secure boot disabled), however, after different tries I was not able to get a boot menu (either GRUB or rEFInd) to select an OS :(

I tried to install rEFInd in my hard disk, however, when booting it goes directly to windows.

I tried again boot repair, nothing happen.

I tried dpkg-reconfigure, nothing happen.

Here is the last bootinfo summary I got.

    http://paste.ubuntu.com/7651147/

The only way for now to enter Xubuntu in my computer is using rEFInd USB with secure boot disabled.

Thanks for your help,

Any comment is appreciated

Comment: There's no evidence of a rEFInd install on your hard disk. I recommend you try again. If necessary, follow the manual installation instructions and, if any errors crop up, post details.

Comment: Hi Rod, I removed rEFInd after I saw it didn't work. I installed again, and didn't work. When I turn on the computer it boots directly in Windows. Here is the boot info summary http://paste.ubuntu.com/7660764/ I don't know if there is any additional configuration needed. I tried removing the file /boot/efi/EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi when I did it GRUB starts ok, but I wasn't be able to enter Windows that way. Thanks for your help

Comment: In Windows, try opening an *Administrator* command prompt window and typing `bcdedit /set {bootmgr} path \EFI\refind\shimx64.efi`. When you reboot, you may need to locate rEFInd's key file. If you still boot straight to Windows, try updating your firmware and try again with `bcdedit`. If that fails and the computer is still within the return period, return it for a refund, because your firmware is broken. If that's not an option, look into [alternative naming options](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/installing.html#naming) for rEFInd (or GRUB).

Comment: Within Windows I use bcdedit program

> bcdedit /set {bootmgr} path /EFI/ubuntu/grubx64.efi

After reboot I went straight to Windows.

So I tried the alternative naming options. I changed the file bootmgfw.efi from /EFI/Microsoft/Boot/ to /EFI/Microsoft/ and copied grubx64.efi to /EFI/Microsoft/Boot/ and rename it to bootmgfw.efi. However when reboot it goes directly to Windows.

Comment: I tried 
> bcdedit /enum all gives: http://paste.ubuntu.com/7688031

It looks like {bootmgr} is ignoring the path I am giving to it and goes directly to {current} setup in display order. I modified displayorder:
> bcdedit.exe /set {bootmgr} displayorder {b83705c7-fa76-11e3-be91-806e6f6e6963}
http://paste.ubuntu.com/7688052/

at reboot: 
>Windows Failed to start. A recent hardware or sofrware change might be the cause.
...
>File: \EFI\ubuntu\grubx64.efi
>
>Status: 0xc000007b
>
>Info: The application or operating system couldn't be loaded because a required file is missing or contains errors

Comment: I used a Windows USB recovery disk to be able to fix the bcd. Within Windows recovery shell I run

>bcdedit /enum all

I here is the output http://paste.ubuntu.com/7688187/

The Ubuntu entry does not appear.

I fixed the displayorder for {bootmgr} and I was able to enter Windows again.

Any comment on this behavior?

Comment: The "...recent hardware or software change..." message sounds like one that's generated by some versions of shim, and indicates a Secure Boot violation. Thus, you should go into your firmware to disable Secure Boot. Once that's done, try using `bcdedit` to set GRUB as the default boot program. Also, note that you've got to use backslashes (`\\`), not slashes (`/`), in filenames in Windows. I think you did so, but the command you quoted above used slashes.

Comment: Hi Rod, I already disabled Secure Boot. Same message appears. the '/' was a typing mistake, it was ok in the command used.

Comment: I remove the following values from {bootmgr} `resumeobject, displayorder`. Using `bcdedit /deletevalue {bootmgr} displayorder`. After doing that, all of the files I set up in  `path` of {bootmgr} gave me the black screen message `Windows Failed to start. A recent hardware...`. I tried \EFI\Boot\bootx64.efi; \EFI\Microsoft\Boot\bootmgfw.efi; \EFI\Microsoft\Boot\bootmgr.efi; \EFI\refind\grubx64.efi; \EFI\refind\shimx64.efi; \EFI\ubuntu\grubx64.efi; \EFI\ubuntu\shimx64.efi. It looks like the file that was working was set up in `displayorder` that pointed to \Windows\system32\winload.efi